# Can we move word in a sentence using RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to find out if its possible to move words around using RegEx? Say for example I have a sentence `The ABC Inc` and using RegEx I want to replace it to `ABC Inc, The`. Is this possible? I have to remove a word or extract part of a sentence but i dont know if its possible to move word or add an extra word to your existing sentence? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What language are you using? You should look into capture groups for this. If you're doing this in a text editor, usually you can use the find and replace function and replace by notation like `\1` and `\2`. If you're doing this programmatically, it is just string manipulation.

Comment: Can you give a sample input so we can write a regex that will work for all inputs?